# How to cast the return of a callback to a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, callback

I have a code in typescript in which I have an array data. This array contains data like

```
[ {employee:"Jason",employeeRole:"teacher",id:10,gender:"male"}, 
{employee:"Mark",employeeRole:"student",id:10,gender:"male"}, ... ].
```

I have to display this data in a grid and the mapping is done through a variable of string type of the grid(field),

```
field: this.data.for(function(arrayItem) 
    var x = arrayItem.employee + " > " +arrayItem.employeeRole;
    return x;
});
```

It tells me that the x is of string type but field is of void,(when it is of type string). But why is it so and how could I make field of type string.

Comment: Your `x` variable will be a string, because it is set by concatenating three strings together. You can't cast it to be even more of a string than it already is. The problem is that although your callback returns a string, the `.for()` function isn't returning that individual string value.

Comment: *Note*: 4 spaces will make the text into code formatting (*back ticks will also work for small code snippets*), you can also highlight and use the  command `Ctrl+K`.

Comment: why is .for not returning the value @nnnnnn

Comment: I don't know Angular2 or Typescript, but I would assume the `.for()` function simply iterates over the array and doesn't return a value at all (or returns `undefined` or the Typescript equivalent). That's what the JS native `.forEach()` function does. Check the doco.

Comment: I just want to assign the concatenated string to the field

Answer (score 0):

You could use a typescript get property:

```
   get field() : string {
        let x = '';
        this.data.forEach(arrayItem => {
            x += arrayItem.employee + " > " +arrayItem.employeeRole;
        });
        return x;
    }
```